# How do I use this Ammo/Potion/Torch Field on one of the official alternate character sheets?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-sheets

I know these three fields help keep track of stuff, but I wondering how it's supposed to be used. How do I use these Ammo/Potion/Torch fields on one of the official alternate character sheets?

[image: cutout of ammo/potion/torch area of character sheet]

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 3):

## However you find most useful

Exactly how to use any one piece of a character sheet isn't prescribed by the rules. Different players and different characters will prefer and require different information noted, tracked and structured. There's multiple official version to accommodate this, you'll find countless different online, and some of us make custom sheets to fit our specific needs.

That said, specific elements are useful for specific types of counting. Textboxes are good at tracking text or big numbers and chains of circles good at counting (low numbers). So, for instance you could put your total number of arrows in the textbox by the arrows and as you spend arrows (by firing them presumably) you tick of circles. In a similar fashion you might note down a type of (healing) potion in one of the potion boxes and use the associated chain of marks to note how many you have, and erase the marks (or use an override mark)<sup>†</sup> when it is used.

The key for using any part of a character sheet (or any character sheet) is to find what works best for you, so that you don't have to spend time searching or interpreting your character sheet and can spend more time actually playing. Try things out, do what feels natural, and don't be afraid to change things if they don't work. And don't worry about others being able to read it, they wont need to read it often and its hard to make it guessable (unless you actually try for that, for some reason.

---

†: Personally I'm fond of using one line to mark something and using a second, crossing line to un-mark it. Saves using a rubber to turn the sheet crumpled and grey. Use what works best for you.